# Does anyone have memory utilization benchmark for random forest and xgboost?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, random-forest, xgboost

I want to compare which technique has higher memory utilization while training on the same dataset

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). 
All what you need to do is to decorate your training function:

```
@profile
def train_xgb():
   gb = xgb.XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100, subsample=0.8, max_depth=6)
   gb.fit(new_trainX,new_trainY)
```